# Don't get firebase token when I use firebase-ui in gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the following command to get a token from `firebase`:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Everything works great but when I use the following command in gradle I get the error:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

My logcat is:

```
Process: ir.bitafaraz.dpnaadmin, PID: 17325
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx.getNoBackupFilesDir
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at ir.bitafaraz.dpnaadmin.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:250)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4457)
at com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout$PerformClickEvent.run(MaterialRippleLayout.java:648)
at com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout$3.onAnimationEnd(MaterialRippleLayout.java:336)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet$AnimatorSetListener.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorSet.java:818)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1078)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:53)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:649)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:665)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:768)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:581)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:754)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.bitafaraz.dpnaadmin"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }           
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: seems like a proguard problem to me.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar So what should I do?

Comment: @ChandraSekhar I do not have any code in proguard.

Comment: Proguard is code obfuscation and minimization. But it isn't enabled, so that is not the problem

Comment: Try using firebase-ui version 1.2.0 instead ([source](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android))

Comment: @LunarWatcher I get this error: failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0

Comment: @LunarWatcher I tried, but to no avail

Comment: Now suddenly the issue is on twitter SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed version firebase to 1.1.1 and firebase messaging to 10.0.1:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

And then add this command to application tag in `Manifest.xml`:

```
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

And Add this command to gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        // Required for 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}
```